# Docusign - Admin consent for external applications. Fails to get oauth token for admin consent

Tags: docusignapi

Per the documentation at [Admin consent for external applications](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent#admin-consent-for-external-applications), I set scope to 'open_id' and gave the consent (using admin user) on the resulting consenting screen. However, when I subsequently try to get the oauth token via `/oauth/token` with userid of the admin, it fails with `{"error":"consent_required"}`

What I am trying to accomplish is to get full admin consent (via JWT service integration) once and then use that consent to send envelopes on behalf of other users (without having to have each user give individual consent).

Answer (score 0):

The **Admin consent for external applications** is a tricky flow. From your original question, it sounds like you did not fulfill all of the requirements of the flow.

In addition, are you sure you need this flow? It's really only needed by ISVs who are selling software to customers who will use the software with their DocuSign accounts. Is that your use case?

Potential issues raised by your question:

1. You need to be an **Organization administrator**. Your question indicates that you are an **account** administrator.
2. You need to have Organization Administration enabled for your account. To enable Org Admin for your account on the demo/developer sandbox system please contact your DocuSign representative.
3. The URL used to start the flow needs to include the `admin_consent_scope` field. For subsequent JWT usage, the `admin_consent_scope` request should be `signature%20impersonation`

Next steps: please check the above issues. Also, please **edit** your question to include the URL you're using to gain consent. (mask out your client_id value)